# Having 2 dropdownlist problem

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have 2 dropdownlist and I needed a default value to appear as the 1st item but one of then **ddlSize** isn't getting the default value, I also tried to create 2 separate functions **TypeColor** & TypeSize but it didn't help, any advice? Thanks:

```
 &nbsp;<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlColor" OnDataBinding='<%# TypeSelection((int)Eval("ProductID")) %>' runat="server" Width="109">
   <asp:ListItem Value="Select Color&nbsp;&nbsp;"></asp:ListItem>
   </asp:DropDownList>
   <br />
   &nbsp;<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSize" OnDataBinding='<%# TypeSelection((int)Eval("ProductID")) %>' runat="server" Width="109">
   <asp:ListItem Value="Select Size&nbsp;&nbsp;"></asp:ListItem>
   </asp:DropDownList>


  protected string TypeSelection(int pID)
        {
            DropDownList ddlColor = (DropDownList)FormView_Product.Row.Cells[0].FindControl("ddlColor");
            DropDownList ddlSize = (DropDownList)FormView_Product.Row.Cells[0].FindControl("ddlSize");
            CommerceEntities db = new CommerceEntities();

            ddlColor.DataSource = from p in db.ProductTypes
                                 where p.ProductID == pID
                                  orderby p.Color 
                                 select new { p.ProductID, p.Color };
            ddlColor.DataTextField = "Color"; 
            ddlColor.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Color", "NA")); //----->Default value

            ddlSize.DataSource = from p in db.ProductTypes
                                 where p.ProductID == pID
                                 orderby p.Size descending
                                 select new { p.ProductID, p.Size };
            ddlSize.DataTextField = "Size";
            ddlSize.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Size", "NA")); //----->Default value(can't get this into the DDL.)

            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like that.

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddl" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
        <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="Default Value"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

This way the default item will be kept there after binding.

Comment: I think that is a best approach.

Answer (score 1):

Call `ddlSize.DataBind();` before inserting the Default value. e.g.

```
ddlSize.DataTextField = "Size";
ddlSize.DataBind(); // Add this
ddlSize.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Size", "NA"));
```

The second thing is not related to your problem, but I need to tell you that you don't need to define your method `return type as String.` Since you are not returning any value from this method, simply make this method `return type Void`

Answer (score 0):

Try to call ddlSize.DataBind() and ddlColor.DataBind() before inserting the default item.

```
ddlColor.DataSource = ...
ddlColor.DataTextField = "....";
ddlColor.DataBind();
ddlColor.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Color", "NA"));
```

And so on ...